# How to use the PATH variable as a starting-point in find within zsh

Tags: command-line, find, zsh

I try to use $PATH as input to find in order to find files defined by my path. This is my attempt:

```
find ${PATH//:/ } -iname "*chrome*"
```

Here I replace all `:` in `PATH` with space, so the starting-points list looks like when you type in manually. Problem is, this is the response:

```
find: ‘/home/martin/bin /home/martin/.local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin’: No such file or directory
```

The variable is interpreted as a whole string instead of multiple space-separated paths.

This particular problem can be solved using xargs like this:

```
echo $PATH | xargs -d: -Ix find x -iname "*chrome*"
```

I'm still curious how to make the first attempt work. I bet that one is better performance-wise too. I'm using zsh on my system. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using a shell like zsh, which disables [word splitting on variable expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html). If you're indeed using zsh, then you need to force expansion by either emulating `sh` (`emulate sh`) or using `${=PATH//:/ }`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" ${PATH//:/ }
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin
$ printf "%s\n" ${=PATH//:/ }
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
$ (emulate sh; printf "%s\n" ${PATH//:/ })
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
```

If you're indeed using bash, check your IFS:

```
$ (IFS=; printf "%s\n" ${PATH//:/ })
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin
$ (IFS=; unset IFS; printf "%s\n" ${PATH//:/ })
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
```

Setting `IFS` to an empty string disables word splitting in bash. You can *unset* `IFS` to get the default value and re-enable word splitting.

Comment: @Zanna Works fine for me in bash. What does `printf "%q" "$IFS"` report for you?

Comment: I indeed use zsh! Using described solution works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin In that case, do remember to specify the shell next time you ask a question that involves shell features (like the `$[var//../..}` string substitution)